# Prestashop filemanager Error 500

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, prestashop

I have a problem in the backoffice and especially in tinyMCE. When I want to add an image a 500 error appears

[image]

The strangest in all this is that it loads all the files up to the letter "L"

---

this is what I have in the console. Tell me if I have to find another mistake.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment the htaccess/htpasswd authentification at the root of your project and test again.

```
#AuthType Basic
#AuthUserFile /home/yourwebsite/public_html/.htpasswd
#Require valid-user
```

And turn "On" Error in config/defines.inc.php

It can be the source of your problem.

let me know